# Powershell - output a foreach loop to one line

Tags: powershell, foreach

I am trying to take the output of my foreach loop and apply the array to a string that reads on one line. Here is my code so far:

```
$upper = 65..90
$lower = 97..122
foreach ($i in $upper)
{
[char]$i 
}
foreach ($i in $lower)
{
[char]$i
}
```

I'm guessing I need to convert the output of the scriptblock to a variable and use the -join option, but everywhere I look I'm struggling to find how to structure that. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular case, [`ForEach(type convertToType)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.2#foreachtype-converttotype) is very useful, here is a cool way to get your lower and upper case dictionary string:

```
$lowerDict = [string]::new(([int][char]'a'..[int][char]'z').ForEach([char]))
$upperDict = $lowerDict.ToUpper()
```

If you have access to PowerShell Core, it can be reduced to:

```
$lowerDict = [string]::new('a'..'z')
$upperDict = $lowerDict.ToUpper()
```

As for what you are struggling on, how to do it with what you currently have (a `foreach` loop). You can capture all the output from the loop first:

```
$upper = foreach ($i in 65..90) { [char]$i }
```

Now, `$upper` is an array of chars, then to convert it to *string*, you can either use `-join` (guessed right) or `[string]::new(...)` as I did on my previous example:

```
$upperDict = -join $upper
# OR
$upperDict = [string]::new($upper)
```

Comment: That makes sense. I ended up using the  [string]::new method and it's working as intended. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @SamR.F. happy to help! please, consider accepting the answer if it was helpful